# In a bash shell script, how to insert a whitespace with regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, sed

here is my script

```
#!bin/bash

STRING1='abcdefg'
STRING2='1234567'
SEDPARSE1='sed -e s/.*(bc).*(23).*/\1\t\2/g'
SEDPARSE2='sed -e s/.*(bc).*(23).*/\1\s\2/g'
SEDPARSE3='sed -e s/.*(bc).*(23).*/\1 \2/g'

echo "${STRING1}${STRING2}" | ${SEDPARSE1}
echo "${STRING1}${STRING2}" | ${SEDPARSE2}
echo "${STRING1}${STRING2}" | ${SEDPARSE3}
```

only SEDPARSE1 works, but it inserts a "tab" not a "whitespace".
SEDPARSE2 and SEDPARSE3 does not work

is there something wrong in my script? thanks!

I expect the result is "bc 23", where the character between "bc" and "23" is a whitespace, not a tab.

Comment: Don't store commands in variables, it causes all sorts of confusion and problems. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Fixed also your sed syntax in my answer. @GordonDavisson: already in my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

string1='abcdefg'
string2='1234567'
# add tab
sedparse1() { sed -E 's/.*(bc).*(23).*/\1\t\2/g' <<< "$1"; }
# trying to add space, the wrong way
sedparse2() { sed -E 's/.*(bc).*(23).*/\1\s\2/g' <<< "$1"; }
# add space
sedparse3() { sed -E 's/.*(bc).*(23).*/\1 \2/g' <<< "$1"; }

sedparse1 "${string1}${string2}" 
sedparse2 "${string1}${string2}"
sedparse3 "${string1}${string2}"
```

Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here.

Your shebang `#!bin/bash` was wrong, corrected here.

---

**I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!**

Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables! There are many situations in which people try to shove commands, or command arguments, into variables and then run them. Each case needs to be handled separately.

[BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

---

[Don't use UPPER case variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/465183)

---

Fixed your `sed` syntax errors. Basically, you need to use `-E` (`ERE` aka *`E`xtended `R`egular `E`xpression*) flag, not `-e` (`BRE` aka *`B`asic `R`egular `E`xpression*) with this syntax.